# why don't javascript object property descriptors always default to false (as per spec)

Tags: javascript, object, properties, attributes

According to the [spec](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Description) when adding a javascript object property, the following defaults will be applied to property descriptors:

- configurable: false
- enumerable: false
- writable: false

However when assigning an object property using the following (very popular) dot notation method they all default to true.

```
myObject = {};
myObject.a = 1;
```

Why is this?

Comment: When assigning a property value using either dot or bracket notation, the object's internal `[[Put]]` method is used (see [*ECMA-262 §8.12.5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5)). Methods like *defineProperties* were added in ed 5 to provide flexibility and have default behaviours different to dot and bracket notation (otherwise you'd use dot or bracket notation). ;-)

Comment: ok thanks - that's helpful - so _defineProperties_ was added afterwards as an alternative ?  why then does the MDN wiki describe the _alternative_ functionality as default rather than the original dot / bracket notation ?

Comment: You may be taking *default* in the wrong context. There is the default behaviour of creating properties through assignment, and a different default behaviour for *defineProperty*. I guess it made sense at the time in the context of extending the ECMAScript ed 3 behaviour of creation through assignment. It may not make as much sense if you start at ES5. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently - again according to a *non-obvious* part of the spec - it is due to the *way* the object property is defined.
See [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#Example:_Adding_properties_and_default_values)

---

If an object property is defined using the `dot notation` method:

```
var myObject={}; 
myObject.a=1;
```

then all property descriptors default to ***true***

---

If an object property is defined using the `bracket notation` method:

```
var myObject = {};
myObject["a"] = 1;
```

then all property descriptors default to ***true***

---

However if an object property is defined using the `defineProperty` method:

```
var myObject={}; 
Object.defineProperty(myObject, 'a', { value: 1 });
```

any undefined descriptors default to ***false***.

---

See an example in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/goredwards/ng90reyo/)

Comment: The relevant part of the specification is the bit that describes the internal `[[Put]]` method: [*ECMA-262 §8.12.5*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.12.5). MDN is a public wiki that anyone can contribute to, it's not authoritative (but is extremely useful). It's no more "non–obvious" than any other part: *Simple Assignment* uses *PutValue*, which than calls the internal *Put* method (step 4.b). ;-)

Comment: fair point that the MDN isn't really the spec - even if it's the only thing most people will read :-)  To me it's _non-obvious_ if it states "Writable. **Defaults to false**" etc. in bold letters, when that's only true 1/3 of the time (if you count 1 out of 3 methods of dot, bracket and defineProperty) ;-)

Comment: See my comment on the OP, *defintProperty/ies* was added later so it made sense to give it different default behaviour (to the spec. authors at least).

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue that confuse a lot of new developers/programmers/engineers. There are two methods that contribute to this issue in the MDN. If you look at the Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor() method in the MDN. It says that writable, enumerable, and configurable all default to false, but when you use the method all will return true (Yes, they are false by default).

**Example:**

```js
let user = {
  name: "John"
};

let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user, 'name');

console.log( JSON.stringify(descriptor, null, 2 ) );
/* property descriptor:
{
  "value": "John",
  "writable": true,
  "enumerable": true,
  "configurable": true
}
*/
```

Now, If you use the Object.defineProperty() method then you will see that the special property attributes are set to false by default. In the example below you will notice, because I didn't set an special attributes all of the properties are false by default.

**Example:**

```js
let user = {};

Object.defineProperty(user, "name", {
  value: "John"
});

let descriptor = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(user, 'name');

console.log( JSON.stringify(descriptor, null, 2 ) );
/*
{
  "value": "John",
  "writable": false,
  "enumerable": false,
  "configurable": false
}
 */
```

I know this is confusing for most people that are new to JavaScript, but I wouldn't try to overthink it. Keep it Simple...